# What file is the </body> tag located in Genesis default theme?

Tags: html, genesis-theme-framework

I need to add some tracking code for Aweber and they said to add it before the `</body>` tag. I've looked through all the Genesis files and cannot find it!

Answer (score 1):

In **every** good theme, the `</body>` tag is located in the `footer.php` file.

However, unless you're using a child theme, any modification will be lost on a theme update. That's why it's better to use the `wp_footer` filter hook like so:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wpse_76330_aweber_tracking_code' );

function wpse_76330_aweber_tracking_code() { ?>

    %%%% insert tracking code here %%%%

<?php }
```